# MySQL select records where there are multiple matching records in related table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

pages table contains field `id`

pages2categories table contains fields `page` and `category`

I want to select records from the pages table

```
where (there is a record in the pages2categories table 
WHERE pages2categories::page = pages::id AND pages2categories:: category = 'X') 
AND (there is also a record in the pages2categories table WHERE pages2categories::page = pages::id AND pages2categories:: category = 'Y') 
AND (there is also a record in the pages2categories table WHERE pages2categories::page = pages::id AND pages2categories:: category = 'Z')
```

In other words, returning a record from the pages table only if all three matching records exist in the pages2categories table.

EXAMPLE:

**pages::id**

```
1

2

3
```

**pages2categories::page, pages2categories::category**

```
1, x

1, y

2, x

2, y

2, z

3, x
```

Result should return just record 2 from the pages table.

I hope this is clear. Thanks!

Comment: And what should be returned in case such record does not exist? What I am aiming here at is - do you want to at the end get a list of values, that do meet your requirements, or do you want to perform a check if a specific value complies with the requirements you stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROm TABLE2 B WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND B.category = 'X') 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROm TABLE2 B WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND B.category = 'Y')
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROm TABLE2 B WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND B.category = 'Z')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks! I don't know whether it is any more or less efficient than the other solutions suggested, but for my purposes efficiency is not so important, and this is the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you wrote:

> In other words, returning a record from the pages table only if all three matching records exist in the pages2categories table.

You also wrote that the query should return 2 rows with the sample data you provided but based on your data, only one row has all 3 categories (page 2).

So, I'm not sure I understand it correctly but here's one way to accomplish it:

```
SELECT p.* FROM page p
LEFT JOIN pages2categories cx ON (cx.page = p.id AND cx.category = 'x')
LEFT JOIN pages2categories cy ON (cy.page = p.id AND cy.category = 'y')
LEFT JOIN pages2categories cz ON (cz.page = p.id AND cz.category = 'z')
WHERE cx.category IS NOT NULL
AND  cy.category IS NOT NULL
AND  cz.category IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from table
group by id
where count(distinct category) = (select count(distinct category) from table)
```